# List structure for multi line strings in Python

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I am struggling to write a multiple choice quiz in Python using list, dictionary or SQLite. All examples I can find show simple 1-word lists or dictionaries. My questions span multiple lines and sometimes have combination answers like I., II., III., IV.  In the past, all this work has been hidden from me by using Delphi 5 or 6 software which I can no longer keep working with .NET.  My data is in the form of word documents, and I have had success in formatting (parsing?) the data with single, double or triple quotes using Kotlin but can't get it to work in an SQLite database.  A sample question of the highest complexity is:

7. Which of the following statements is/are not true about assessment?
   I. Feedback is the most important factor in assessment.
   II. Only those that can be objectively measured should be taught.
   III. Assessment should follow a developmental pattern.
   IV. Identifying systematic errors committed by students should be the basis of remedial instruction.
   A. II only
   B. IV only
   C. III and IV
   D. I and II

Can somebody point me in the right direction, please?  I need to know what kind of structure either SQLite needs or list, dictionary structure in Python so I can pass these questions into a form. Please excuse if I don't appear to answer as I have no practice using Stack except in reading other people's answers.

1. Which holds true to standardized tests?
   A. They are used for comparative purposes
   B. They are administered differently
   C. They are scored according to different standards
   D. They are used for assigning grades
2. A negative discrimination index of a test item tells that particular test item lacks         .
   A. objectivity
   B. reliability
   C. content validity
   D. construct validity
3. In his second item analysis, Teacher H found out that more from the lower group got the test item # 6 correctly. This means that the test item                 .
   A. has a negative discriminating power
   B. has a lower validity
   C. has a positive discriminating power
   D. has a high reliability

Comment: Can you please add more examples and code you've tried?

Comment: I haven't written any code because I am still trying to input even 1 question into a dictionary or a list.  I am not a programmer, but a retired truck driver.

Comment: 4. You want to teach concepts, patterns, and abstractions. Which method is most appropriate?
A. deductive method
B. problem solving
C. direct instruction
D. indirect instruction



5. Which can enhance the development of spatial intelligence?
A. hands-on demonstrations
B. environmental study
C. concept miming
D. concept mapping
6. Which of these is not an indicator of a supportive learning environment?
A. high drop-out rates
B. warm and friendly atmosphere
C. students take personal responsibility for their learning and behavior
D. increase in student bonding activities

Comment: Could you clarify **1.** what _specifically_ you're having trouble with? You say you've had success parsing the data with Kotlin but can't _get it to work_ with SQLite? What do you mean by that? Where do you run into a problem? **2.** what you're trying to achieve -- just save the parsed questions into a database? Read them from the database into a python program? **3.** What do your points numbered 1--6 (in question and comments) have to do with your question? Are they example questions you need to save? **4.** Do you expect there to be only one correct answer (eg A) or multiple (eg A and D)

Comment: I will try to explain in more detail. these tests are available for free for Philippine students to study for their Licensure Examination.  I am trying to put them into a usable app that will help to reinforce their learning comprehension.  I cannot get python or sqlite to accept any of the questions because I have never seen any example using long data.  A sample of the raw data is:  https://www.teachpinas.com/download/assessment-of-learning-and-evaluation-part-1-profed/

Comment: I am trying to put the questions with their answers into an sqlite database.  I tried using various separators such as *.or tilde.  I would be happy to put them into a list or dictionary.  It would be nice to read them from a database .  numbers 1 to 6 are not points but actual questions with answers.

Comment: Yes there is 1 correct answer as a, b,c, or d.  If i could see 1 question and answer put into a usable list or dictionary, that would help immensely.

Comment: Thank you, Pranav for your reply. After looking at your questions I realized a dictionary is not what I needed but rather, ReadLine() at runtime.